# How to identify Locale change and orientation change in onConfigurationChanged()

Tags: android, orientation, locale, multilingual

I am making an application multi lingual and handling orientation as well and i want to logout the user if Locale is changed i implemented this but now when user change orientation then it will logout the user.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    boolean deviceLanguageOverridenWithDefaultLanguage = PersistentManager.isDeviceLanguageOverridenWithDefaultLanguage();

    if(deviceLanguageOverridenWithDefaultLanguage)
    {
        AppUtil.setApplicationLanguage(AppConstants.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
    }

    if(AppUtil.isSupportedLanguage(newConfig.locale))
    {   
        UIUtil.showLogoutAlertDialog(this, getString(R.string.dialog_log_out_message_change_language_log_out), getString(R.string.dialog_log_out_title_log_out), false);
    }
}
```